# JOIN 2 Table with sum, count, group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to combine 2 queries to make one table. Here is my query:

First:

```
SELECT namas, SUM(jumlahtransaksi) as sum, COUNT(statustransaksi) as count
FROM dbtransaksi
where statustransaksi='Tertagih'
GROUP BY namas
```

Second:

```
SELECT jeniskegiatan, namas, COUNT(jeniskegiatan)
FROM dbkegiatan
GROUP by jeniskegiatan, namas
```

My query did not work and I am unsure why

```
SELECT dbkegiatan.namas, dbkegiatan.jeniskegiatan,
       COUNT(dbkegiatan.jeniskegiatan) as count1, dbtransaksi.namas,
       sum(dbtransaksi.jumlahtransaksi) as sum, COUNT(dbtransaksi.statustransaksi) as count
from dbkegiatan
    left outer join dbtransaksi on dbkegiatan.namas=dbtransaksi.namas
where dbtransaksi.statustransaksi='Tertagih'
group by dbkegiatan.namas, dbkegiatan.jeniskegiatan, dbtransaksi.namas
```

The result
[image: from my query]
but I want to combine the 2 query results from earlier:
[image: first result]
[image: and second result to be one table]
**dbkegiatan**

```
|id_keg | nip   | namas | jeniskegiatan  |
|KEG001 | 203004| Amin  |Visit/Presentasi|
|KEG002 | 203004| Amin  |Visit/Presentasi|
|KEG003 | 203005| Budi  |Demo Produk     |
|KEG004 | 203006| Cecep |Lost Project    |
|KEG005 | 203007| Dedi  |Customer Baru   |
|KEG006 | 203004| Amin  |Demo Produk     |
|KEG007 | 203005| Budi  |Visit/Presentasi|
|KEG008 | 203006| Cecep |Demo Produk     |
|KEG009 | 203007| Dedi  |Lost Project    |
|KEG010 | 203004| Amin  |Cross/Up Selling|
```

**dbtransaksi**

```
|id_trans| nip   | namas | jumlahtransaksi | statustransaksi|
|TRA001  |0203004| Amin  |250000000        |Tertagih        |
|TRA002  |0203005| Budi  |400000000        |Tertagih        |
|TRA003  |0203005| Budi  |250000000        |Tertagih        |
|TRA004  |0203006| Cecep |80000000         |Tertagih        |
|TRA005  |0203007| Dedi  |128000000        |Tertagih        |
|TRA006  |0203007| Dedi  |452500000        |Belum Tertagih  |
|TRA007  |0203004| Amin  |250000000        |Belum Tertagih  |
```

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Comment: What you are asking is unclear. Queries do not return the same columns, how to you want to combine them ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve, but i think this is what you are after

```
  SELECT dbkegiatan.namas, dbkegiatan.jeniskegiatan,
           COUNT(dbkegiatan.jeniskegiatan) as count1, dbtransaksi.namas,
           sum(dbtransaksi.jumlahtransaksi) as sum, COUNT(dbtransaksi.statustransaksi) as count
    from dbkegiatan
        left outer join dbtransaksi on dbkegiatan.namas=dbtransaksi.namas AND dbtransaksi.statustransaksi='Tertagih'
    group by dbkegiatan.namas, dbkegiatan.jeniskegiatan, dbtransaksi.namas
```

Answer (score 0):

Still not following you 100% are you trying to union join the tables if so the following should work

```
SELECT '' AS jeniskegiatan namas, SUM(jumlahtransaksi) as sum, COUNT(statustransaksi) as count
FROM dbtransaksi
where statustransaksi='Tertagih'
GROUP BY namas

UNION

SELECT jeniskegiatan, namas, '' as sum, COUNT(jeniskegiatan) AS count
FROM dbkegiatan
GROUP by jeniskegiatan, namas
```